# how to split java string by (?

Tags: java, regex

I need to use the split method with "(".

```
   String statement=" i m a test statement ( i need help ";
   String[] myArray=statement.split("(");
```

that my code .

Comment: For future reference, please try to include the full text of the error you're getting, and the circumstances in which it occurs.  For instance, in this case you could include the full stack trace of the `PatternSyntaxException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `(` character:

```
String[] myArray=statement.split("\\(");
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `(` :

```
String statement=" i m a test statement ( i need help ";
String[] myArray=statement.split("\\(");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Output :

```
[ i m a test statement ,  i need help ]
```